# Oracle R Enterprise: Error ORE object has no unique key

Tags: r, oracle, enterprise

I need to make a function which call Oracle R Enterprise ore.corr function and output result as a data.frame.

My R code here:

```
f_sts_corelation = 
function(dat, target_col="",corr_type="spearman",group_by="")
{
    v_target_col = gsub("\n","",target_col, fixed = TRUE);
    v_target_col_list = "";
    library("gdata");
    for (s_name in strsplit(v_target_col,",")[[1]])
    {
      n_pos = regexpr(".",s_name,fixed = TRUE);
      if (n_pos > 0)
      {
        s_name = substring(s_name,n_pos+1);
      }

      s_name = gsub("\"","",s_name, fixed = TRUE);
      if (is.numeric(dat[,trim(s_name)])) 
      {
        if (nchar(v_target_col_list)== 0)
        {
          v_target_col_list = trim(s_name)
        }
        else
        {
          v_target_col_list =paste(v_target_col_list,",",trim(s_name))
        }
      }
    }

    ore.data = ore.push(dat)

    v_id = c()
    v_group=c()
    v_row = c()
    v_col = c()
    v_statistic = c()
    v_pvalue = c()
    v_df = c()

    #group_by = ""

    s_group_by = trim(gsub("\n","",group_by, fixed = TRUE));

    if (nchar(s_group_by) > 0)
    {
      n_pos = regexpr(".",s_group_by,fixed = TRUE);
      if (n_pos > 0)
      {
        s_group_by = substring(s_group_by,n_pos+1);
      }
      s_group_by = trim(gsub("\"","",s_group_by, fixed = TRUE));

      ore.corr.res = ore.corr(ore.data,var = v_target_col_list, group.by = s_group_by)
      for (i in 1:length(ore.corr.res))
      {
        if (i == 1)
        {
          v_group = rep(names(ore.corr.res[i]),length(ore.corr.res[[i]]$ROW))
          v_row = as.vector(ore.corr.res[[i]]$ROW)
          v_col = as.vector(ore.corr.res[[i]]$COL)
          v_statistic =  as.vector(ore.corr.res[[i]][,3])
          v_pvalue = as.vector(ore.corr.res[[i]][,4])
          v_df = as.vector(ore.corr.res[[i]][,5])
        }
        else
        {
          v_group = c(v_group,rep(names(ore.corr.res[i]),length(ore.corr.res[[i]]$ROW)))
          v_row = c(v_row,as.vector(ore.corr.res[[i]]$ROW))
          v_col = c(v_col,as.vector(ore.corr.res[[i]]$COL))
          v_statistic = c(v_statistic,as.vector(ore.corr.res[[i]][,3]))
          v_pvalue = c(v_pvalue,as.vector(ore.corr.res[[i]][,4]))
          v_df = c(v_df,as.vector(ore.corr.res[[i]][,5]))
        }
      }
    }
    else if(nchar(s_group_by) == 0)
    {
      ore.corr.res = ore.corr(ore.data,var = v_target_col_list)

      v_group = rep(" ",length(ore.corr.res$ROW))
      v_row = as.vector(ore.corr.res$ROW)
      v_col = as.vector(ore.corr.res$COL)
      v_statistic =  as.vector(ore.corr.res[,3])
      v_pvalue = as.vector(ore.corr.res[,4])
      v_df = as.vector(ore.corr.res[,5])
    }

    df_res = data.frame(Group_by = v_group, 
                        Row = v_row, 
                        Col = v_col,
                        Statistic = v_statistic,
                        P_Value = v_pvalue,
                        DF = v_df)
}
```

After that, I run the function by following script:

```
dat = iris;
corr_type="spearman";
V_target_col= '"IRIS_N$10002"."Sepal.Length",
             "IRIS_N$10002"."Sepal.Width",
             "IRIS_N$10002"."Petal.Width",
             "IRIS_N$10002"."Petal.Length"';

group_by = 
'
  "IRIS_N$10002"."Species"
'

df_result = f_sts_corelation(dat,target_col = target_col, group_by = group_by)
```

But following error happen. 
   **Error: ORE object has no unique key**

I have tried to run each R command inside my function step by step and I sure that the Error happen from the last R command:

```
df_res = data.frame(Group_by = v_group, 
                    Row = v_row, 
                    Col = v_col,
                    Statistic = v_statistic,
                    P_Value = v_pvalue,
                    DF = v_df)
```

I don't know how to avoid this error.

Comment: You can use `traceback()` (right after the error occurs) or `debug(your_fun_name)` to localize the error. I cannot run your code. What packages do you use?  What's `target_col`?

Comment: To run this script you have tp install Oracle R Enterprise Package, and load it by library("ORE") command. After that, you have to

Comment: To run this script you have to install **Oracle R Enterprise Package**, and load it by 'library("ORE")' command. After that, you have to create a connection to Oracle Database by command `ore.connect(user = "user", sid = "sid", host = "192.168.100.148",password = "abc123", port = 1521 )`. There is a wrong in my command to call the function. You can call by `df_result = f_sts_corelation(dat,target_col = v_target_col, group_by = group_by)` . I will try to follow you guide. Thanks.